# JS Replace function is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a backend CGI script that returns me below text in case of issues via an AJAX call:

```
<p>A problem occurred in a Python script.
<p> /bin/cgi-bin/LOGS/tmpslM4pu.txt contains the description of this error.
```

I am trying to display it like below:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:  "runcgi.py",
            data:
            {
               'my_data' : 'test'
            },
            success: function(html)
            {
              if(..test for success..)
              {
              }
              else
              {
                            var StrippedString = $(html).toString().replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");                                                                                           var StrippedString = $(html).toString().replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
                            $("p").html(StrippedString);

              }
});
```

And below is my HTML code:

```
<body>
        <p></p>
</body>
```

But I see the below output in my browser:

```
[object Object]
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Use console.log(html) ang Google Chrome, or Firebug in Firefox, and inspect the element in the console view.

Answer (score 3):

You are taking the jQuery object formed by `html` and converting it to a string. The result is `[object OBJECTTYPE]`, which in this case is `[object Object]`.

Instead, just try `var StrippedString = html.replace(...);`.

Comment: I had tried that but it states that html.replace is not a function that is why I added toString(). Using FireBug I see that $(html) has value 'Document'